# cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime

Tags: rust

I have such a thing:

```
type G2d<'a> = GfxGraphics<'a, Resources, CommandBuffer>;
```

How to include it as a field into a structure?

```
pub struct Dc
{
  g : G2d,
  c : Context,
}
```

But it gives:

```
expected named lifetime parameter
```

I tried:

```
pub struct Dc
{
  g : &'a mut G2d<'a>,
  c : Context,
}

window.draw_2d( &event, | c, g, device |
{
  let mut dc = Dc { c, g };
});
```

But it gives:

[image: image|690x385]

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper solution is

```rust
pub struct Dc<'a, 'b>
{
  g : &'a mut G2d<'b>,
  c : Context,
}
```

That's logically improper to have the outer &mut borrow has been created at the same moment as a reference inside G2d<'a> was. So in the expression &'a mut G2d<'a> these both 'a lifetimes can't possibly mean they borrow the same thing. Proper solution is using several lifetimes.

Answer (score 1):

the whole struct should be annotated by the lifetime :

```
pub struct Dc<'a>
{
  g : G2d<'a>,
  c : Context,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I tried what you've suggested and old error is not a problem anymore, but I have a new one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/145Rib8DRhxd4_LB3iUKQ_hy8IDM7Hkt2/view?usp=sharing
Any idea how to fix that?